# JBoss Module java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, jdbc, jboss7.x, jboss-modules

I'm trying to deploy an OrientDB Datasource to JBoss AS7 using their JDBC file, and I keep getting a [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.OSignalHandler from [Module "com.orientechnologies:main" from local module loader @6f4051d1 (roots: /opt/jboss/modules)](http://pastebin.com/MyBXY554) exception (link to a partial stack trace).  Thing is - the .class file is in the same jar as the class that's throwing the error:

```
cmdsl[/opt/jboss/modules/com/orientechnologies/main/]
Tue Apr 14, 15:56:49|vagrant[788]$ ls
module.xml  orientdb-jdbc-2.0.7-all.jar  orientdb-jdbc-2.0.7-all.jar.index

cmdsl[/opt/jboss/modules/com/orientechnologies/main/]
Tue Apr 14, 15:56:50|vagrant[789]$ jar tf orientdb-jdbc-2.0.7-all.jar | grep OSignal
com/orientechnologies/orient/core/OSignalHandler.class
```

I'm not really sure why it's having trouble seeing that.  My server/boot logs don't seem to provide any additional errors.

[module.xml](http://pastebin.com/bn0Z5b4N)

[jar tf orientdb-jdbc-2.0.7-all.jar](http://pastebin.com/index.php?e=1)

I've tried to track down any additional dependencies and expose those as separate modules, I've spent a lot of time trying to find decent documentation on how to build these modules and what the class resolution rules are, but they all seem to point to only needing a depth of two in the folder structure.  Not really sure if there's more I need to put in the META-INF to indicate the locations of these classes.

Comment: What is the structure of the resulting ear file? In general, my best success with loading custom modules in JBoss 7 has been loading the custom jar modules into the root level of the ear.

Comment: @Hypino Actually, this is an attempt to make a datasource available across multiple applications using the `standalone.xml` file.

Comment: Did you add the jboss-deployment-structure.xml to the EAR to add the dependency on your custom module?  What does that look like?